# how to call a page in iframe when clicking hyperlink?

Tags: html

I have a left pane with 5 items as hyperlink. When i click on the hyperlink, i wanna display corresponding item description in the right hand side. 
I am developing the website using html. 
By default there will be some description. when i click on item1, i wanna display the details of item1 and click on item2 i wanna display item2's details.

How can do this? Can i display the page in the iframe or something? what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an IFrame, then you can do so, and just set the target of the hyperlink to be the name of the iFrame.

However, iFrames are considered bad practice. What would be better, is to use JQuery and use the load command.

For example, if your right hand pane has an id of `right-pane`:

```
<a href="showItem('item1-details.html')">item 1</a>

function showItem(url) {
    $('#right-pane').load(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the target  attribute.  :)

http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_frames.asp