# wants that when I click on the any index hyperlink, then it is displayed on main description page

Tags: html

I have made an web page. There are two iframes
In it. First is of index and second one is description page. I want that when I click on the any index hyperlink, then it is displayed on main description page.
How it will be possible? please give me the HTML code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call a page in iframe when clicking hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293272/how-to-call-a-page-in-iframe-when-clicking-hyperlink)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button and when clicking it, change the url of the iFrame using Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('iframe-id').src = newLink;
```

You can use [the data-attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) to store the wanted link in your html.

In case you want to do that: **It is not possible to react to things outside of an iFrame through an iFrame.** So you cannot put a link in iFrame1 and have it reload iFrame2, because those are two different websites and don't see each other.

---

Now, idk what exactly you are planing to do, but I really hope, that you don't want to make your entire site like that. Using iFrames is really only useful for things like inserting widgets (like Codepen etc.), but should never be used to display information from your own site. If you don't want to copy your html for every site then use PHP. If you don't want to reload your entire webpage (which is pretty much never a problem) you can use AJAX-requests to load parts of your website. (Frameworks like React.js, Angular.js and Vue.js do that for you)